# cant access form inside an accordion

Tags: angularjs, accordion

Here's my code sample:

```
<html ng-app="helloApp">
<head>
    <title>HelloWorld</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/example.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hello World Sample Program</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="HelloCtrl">

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="TestForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Type Your Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="name"  class="form-control" value="{{name}}" required/>
                        <span>Hello {{ name }}!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

    </div>

</body>
```

and JavaScript:

```
(function() {

    var helloApp = angular.module("helloApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

    helloApp.controller("HelloCtrl", ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
            // $scope.name = "calvin hobbes";
            $scope.$watch('TestForm.$valid', function() {
                console.log("watching " + $scope.TestForm.$valid);
            });
        }]);
})();
```

This works just fine.

I can see that form is being watched on console and it changes from false to true as I type.

But, I need the form inside an accordion, like this:

```
<div ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
        <accordion close-others="false" >
            <accordion-group is-open="true" is-disabled="false">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="TestForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Type Your Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="name"  class="form-control" value="{{name}}" required/>
                            <span>Hello {{ name }}!</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
    </div>
```

The form is not recognized anymore.

I get the following error. How do I solve it?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined
at Object.fn (example.js:12)
at l.$digest (angular.min.js:124)
at l.$apply (angular.min.js:126)
at angular.min.js:17
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`accordion` and `accordion-group` creates new scope.

`TestForm's` controller will be updated in these scope but not in controller's scope.

To access the `TestForm` in controller's scope make the below code changes.

**Markup**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="forms.TestForm">
```

**Controller**

```
  $scope.forms = {}
  $scope.$watch('forms.TestForm.$valid', function() {
        console.log("watching " + $scope.forms.TestForm.$valid); 
    });
```

Here is the working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/IP6mMY6Jf0zzBoG9kMLx?p=preview

Comment: I've already tried that Vinay. That doesnt work. If you see on the console, even on plunker, the "watching statement" is only logged once, on page load. after that, it wont get updated as you keep typing. Its not really watching on the form.

Comment: @ThePearl watch expression needs to changed to `forms.TestForm.$valid`. Updated the plnkr in the answer.

Comment: yeah that worked. Sorry, I am new to angular. I was watching on `$scope.forms.TestForm.$valid` instead of `forms.TestForm.$valid`.